# Couchbase view documents older than one month

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I am trying to create a couchbase view which retrieve the IDs of all the views that haven't been updated for more than one month.
They also should not have the string ID in their key:

```
function (doc, meta) {

  if (meta.id.indexOf("ID") == -1) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentDateInMillis = currentDate.getTime();
    if (doc.lastTimestampMillis != null && doc.lastTimestampMillis < (currentDateInMillis - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) {
      emit(meta.id, meta.id)
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I have lastTimestampMillis field in my document.

Well, This code doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of implementing the dates checking logic in the view code, just emit `doc.lastTimestampMillis` and then query for the dates you want. E.g. `query.endkey(<now - 30d>)` will give you all the timestamps up to 30 days ago. Since the emitted value only updates when the document changes, the view as you wrote it becomes stale almost immediately. Only emitting the timestamp has the advantage of letting you query any range of dates, as well as actually reflecting the correct timestamps at all times.

Comment: But that will cause a view that contains almost all the documetns in the bucket?

Comment: It won't contain the documents, just the timestamps and document keys. But yes, it will have as many items as there are documents with a timestamp. If you have billions of docs, this could be a lot. But this is the most reliable way to do what you want.